# How to attach a string to an integer in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int

I've got a two letter word that I'd like to attach to a double digit number. The word is an integer and the number is a string.
Say the name of the number is "number" and the name of the word is "word".
How would you make it print both of them together without spaces. When I try it right now it still has a space between them regardless of what I try.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
'{}{}'.format(word, number)
```

For example,

```
In [19]: word='XY'

In [20]: number=123

In [21]: print('{}{}'.format(word, number))
XY123
```

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function has a `sep` parameter that controls spacing between items:

```
print(number, word, sep="")
```

If you need a string, rather than printing, than unutbu's answer with string formatting is better, but this may get you to your desired results with fewer steps.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 the preferred way to construct strings is by using [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)

To print out a word and a number joined together you would use:

```
print("{}{}".format(word, number))
```